# How to get Run's text inside a Hyperlink?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, c#-4.0, wpf-4.0

This is my XAML markup:

```
<TextBlock>
    <Hyperlink Click="InstrumentFile_Click">
        <Run Text="{Binding InstrumentFile}"/>
    </Hyperlink>
</TextBlock>
```

C#:

```
private void InstrumentFile_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Hyperlink link = sender as Hyperlink;
    if (link != null)
    {
        //need to get text here
    }
}
```

I want to get the text that is bound to Run. How can I get? Thanks!

Comment: say what? can you please refraise that title/question

Comment: What problem does it have? On the contrary can you please improve your typos? It's rephrase as I know and not *refraise* :)

Comment: Where do you want to 'get' it? In the `InstrumentFile_Click` method?

Comment: @fguchelaar: Yes. You can check my edit.

Comment: If you're sure the markup (hierarchy) is always like in your example, you could use `((Run)link.Inlines.ElementAt(0)).Text`. But I would consider using some 'safer' code.

Comment: Okay thanks for that. It would work for now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a silly situation.  You've written a class with a InstrumentFile member, and bound to it by the view.  Now you want to programmatically access the view in order to get the data you gave it in the first place?  It's backwards!

Just access the InstrumentFile member directly.  You wrote the code in the first place!

Comment: Not as silly as you think. I haven't implemented MVVM pattern nor am I using INotifyPropertyChanged. The textblock posted here is inside a DataGrid. Could you please clarify how would I know which hyperlink is clicked and access it's text?

Comment: The `sender` property gives you the clicked object, and you know that the `DataContext` of it will be the object it's bound to.  If you really don't want to use MVVM, get the Hyperlink from `sender`, get the object it's bound to, and access the property.  But it's a terrible model which MVVM solves with extreme simplicity and ease

Comment: That's not what I meant - that comment's code will break with a runtime error if you change the view and forget the code.  Just use the object to get the DataContext and grab the class it's bound to.  Less likely to change.  It's a quality issue here caused by lack of a good code structure..